# how to extract a certain number from a website in python

Tags: python, html

I need to make a bot for a client that gets data from http://backpack.tf/stats/Unique/AWPer%20Hand/Tradable/Craftable and does some research.

On the top of the website you see the recomended price (3 ref) and if you scroll down you can see what people are actaully selling them for.

I need to see if what there selling them for is less then the recomended price. I have inspected the element and found that each listing uses a class called "media listing" followed by a random ID. Where do i go from here?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Look into install [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). You'll be able to parse HTML files quite easily. The site also has tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: I have installed beautifull soup and i can not find any tutorial thats up to date on it. I swear im actually looking and not just saying that!

Comment: Once i get the HTML with BS do i just do a simple split? or how would i extract the actual amounts from the webpage?

Comment: @MichaelBecker what exactly do you want from the `recent suggestions` sections? `New` or `Current` or...?

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: k thanks, i just started to piece it together by running random commands with BS. i still have no idea how to extract the number from the class but ill have to figure it out somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), but this should give you a good idea of what you want to do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://backpack.tf/stats/Unique/AWPer%20Hand/Tradable/Craftable"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

curPrice = soup.find('h2').findNext('a').text

print 'The current price is: {0}'.format(curPrice)

print 'These are the prices they are being sold at: '
print '\n'.join([item.text for item in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'label label-black', 'data-tip': 'bottom'})])
```